# Show a notification to the question asker when they try to add a large comment on their own question

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

We all know the situation, new users don't understand that Stack Overflow is not a forum. Therefore if someone asks a question and the question misses relevant information someone will post a comment asking to add information.

The common approach of new users is to answer that comment and "misuse" the comment for adding new and large (unformatted and hard-to-read) information.

Afterwards an experienced Stack Overflow user will post a comment saying something like:
*"Please edit your question instead of posting those info in a comment."*.

IMHO it would be better if Stack Overflow would automatically show such a hint to a questioner, while writing a comment on her/his own question that exceeds a specific length (e.g. 100 characters?).

From my point of view this would be like an integrated "tutorial", explaining the way how Stack Overflow works (Q & A system vs. forum).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'm pretty tired of saying ***"Please edit your question instead of posting those info in a comment."***

Comment: I don't like this. I often write comments longer than ~100 characters. I don't want a nagging popup / hint to pop up every time.

Comment: @Cerbrus As I read it the message is only shown to the asker who writes a comment under their own question. (And also probably just for new users)

Comment: @Rizier123: I also see other users putting blocks of code into comments. It makes no sense to show this popup _only_ to the person asking the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus While that is true I see a tendency that clarification requests for code and other stuff are mostly posted on new user's questions. The new users also then tend to post that information in the comments instead of editing their question.

Comment: Fully agree, yet how often does it happen that you request to edit a question and then the content *still* ends up in comments? Somehow I think this won't help, there is a bigger disconnect going on that makes people not understand they can edit the question, or how.

Comment: Maybe it should not (only) be based on length, but try to detect code pasted into the comment box (for exacmple, language-agnostic: an unusually high number of parenthesis of any kind - `<>()[]{}`)

Comment: @Cerbrus: _"I also see other users putting blocks of code into comments"_ -- yes, but those comments may or may not be a problem. The author of a post putting code into a comment on that same post is almost _certainly_ doing it wrong. The idea here is to get the low-hanging fruit without false positives, not necessarily to solve every possible mistake.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, so, why not show the popup to other users, as well? There's hardly ever a good reason to post a block of code in comments.

Comment: @Cerbrus: _"There's hardly ever a good reason to post a block of code in comments"_ -- Not true. It is quite common for someone to comment to try to help the question author, even though the question itself is unclear and unanswerable. This often involves code, and it's reasonable for someone to post such a comment, in lieu of an answer that quite possibly could be deemed not useful (because it's a _guess_, not an answer). This is very different from the scenario where a post already exists and simply should be improved.

Comment: I'm not talking about corrections, a couple of variables, small things like that. There is hardly ever a good reason to post a large block of code.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the word [edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/333643/edit) beneath the question is rather small and also de-emphasised by lower case, so it doesn't attract the attention of new users.

Comment: The word [edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/333643/edit) could be made bold, or larger, or highlighted by a box, for new users, or users who have never hit it before, or users whose question has received comments containing the text "please edit your question".

Answer (score 16):

Distilled from the comments on this question so far, one possible way would be:

- everyone who comments on his own questions or answers and
- comments with more than 100 characters and
- has rep < XX (XX ~ 250)

Sees a popup that needs to be clicked away with text like "Remember, add new information to your post by editing it instead of commenting." before being able to add the comment.

Why 100 characters? Because additions to questions or answers aren't always code, something they are context, something just the missing information.

Answer (score -3):

You're already warned about this before posting ANY comment on your own question:

> [image: If you're adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting]

I see no reason why anyone who missed that would pick up on any further hints.

Comment: Yellow warning pop ups probably get read more often than placeholder text.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes. Because popups are more obtrusive.

Comment: Placeholder text is completely ignored, unless someone specifically thinks they don't know what they're doing. You've made this system too intuitive, Stack Overflow!

Comment: When I click "add comment", the textarea gets focus immediately and I'm never shown the placeholder unless I deliberately un-focus the textbox.

Comment: "*Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.*" - Rick Cook

Comment: @Bergi I'm shown the placeholder regardless of focus.

Comment: Regardless of the visibility and content of the placeholder, you are producing straw men if your argument doesn't solve the problem which @wizzwizz4 points out.

Comment: This is the first time I am *seeing* that warning.

Comment: @Bergi that might be a bug